# crm 2011 when update a field in account entity there is no change

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Well, my problem is the follow. I create a entity. i call this `new_logpuntossegmentacin` that has a relation 1 to ∞ with account, when i put in the registration plugin message, create i hope that the follow code fill out the field `puntosacumulados` but nothing happens:
cli is a Account from a List
total is a Decimal

```
total = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5 + total6;
cli.new_puntosacumulados.Insert(i, total.ToString());
svcContext.UpdateObject(cli);
svcContext.SaveChanges();

i++;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(total.ToString()))
{
    tracingService.Trace("Response = {0}", total.ToString());
}
tracingService.Trace("Done.");
```

Comment: Can you post the whole method?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of questions which may give a little more context:-

1) When you say nothing happens, do you mean that the value is not updated in the database or it doesn't appear updated on the form? If the latter then it may be when the plug in is firing (pre vs post).
2) Could you perhaps post the rest of the method as it may be useful to get some context on some of the other parameters, e.g. what is "i" iterating over here?

Thanks